# How do I configure pg_search to search against an attribute via delegation in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pg-search

I have a `User` model that gets attributes such as first_name, last_name, etc... via a delegation to a `Profile` model:

```
delegate :first_name, :last_name,
              to: :profile
```

I want to be able to search for another model, Services, which belongs_to a User.

How do I set up the pg_search_scope configuration in my `Service` model so that I can search against first_name, last_name? Here's what I have currently but it doesn't work.

```
pg_search_scope :search_full_text,
                  :against => {
                    :name => 'A',
                    :description => 'B',
                  },
                  :using => {
                    :tsearch => {:dictionary => "english"}
                  },
                  :associated_against => {
                    :skills => [:name],
                    :user => [:first_name, :last_name]
                  }
```

I'm getting this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in SearchController#show

PG::Error: ERROR:  column users.first_name does not exist
LINE 1: ...ER JOIN (SELECT "services"."id" AS id, string_agg("users"."f...
```